# How to set text in android, through a text watcher

Tags: android, dynamic

I have recently created a class that has a text view and an edit text.
I am using the edit text in order to get some input from an user, and I would like for my text view to display what the user types in.
I need to mention that my labels are created dynamically and I am not sure how to reference them.
C0uld you give me a clue?

```
public TextView itemName(Context context){
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView itemName = new EditText(context);
        itemName.setLayoutParams(lparams);

        return itemName;
    }

    public EditText desiredQuantity(Context context) {

        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final EditText desiredQuantity = new EditText(context);
        desiredQuantity.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        desiredQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                itemName.setText(desiredQuantity.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        return desiredQuantity;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IvFR.png)

Comment: Just put settext inside `onTextChanged`

Comment: Please show code directly in your question and not a screen shot. This will help us better answer your question and analyze the code. See this as an example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

`onTextChanged` called when user change the text from edittext.

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        t1.setText(et1.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: It tells me that I cannot resolve the symbol. I should mention that the text view is generated through code in a class